# Apache Neatbeans IDE 20 & Java 17.0 - Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine

Tags: java, windows, netbeans, windows-10

I persist this issue using java **(version "17.0.10")** and **Apache Neatbeans IDE 20** :

`Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine. -Xbootclasspath/p is no longer a supported option. Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\20\executor-snippets\run.xml:111: The following error occurred while executing this line: C:\Users\Test\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\20\executor-snippets\run.xml:68: Java returned: 1 BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)`

Someone who can help me to solve it? Thank you!

Eng. Emmanuel A.

Comment: Please put errors in code blocks instead of code lines